# Highlighting map area based on selection in Altair

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite

I wanted to highlight the part of a map where mouse is hovering (or nearest to) - just like a tooltip behaves - by using `selection_single`. But it always remains fixed at a seemingly random point.

For example, here the county region should be highlighted **red** when mouse is on top of it.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = data.unemployment.url

highlight = alt.selection_single(on='mouseover', nearest=True, fields=['id'], empty='none')

alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color=alt.condition(highlight, alt.value('red'), 'rate:Q'),
    tooltip=['id:Q', 'rate:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).add_selection(highlight).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=600
)
```

[image]
But wherever my mouse goes, both the highlight AS WELL AS THE TOOLTIP remain fixed at `id`  = 22051 (look at bottom in Lousiana). When the selection is not added the tooltip works fine, but after adding the selection, even it fails to work correctly.

Will voronoi tesselation help? Like the nearest line example? I tried, it failed, but I am not sure that I applied it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you remove `nearest=True`:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = data.unemployment.url

highlight = alt.selection_single(on='mouseover', fields=['id'], empty='none')

alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color=alt.condition(highlight, alt.value('red'), 'rate:Q'),
    tooltip=['id:Q', 'rate:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).add_selection(highlight).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=900,
    height=600
)
```

[image]